# Write matching rows in csvfile to a new csv file using Python

Tags: python, csv, split, match, keyword

I am new to python and I am trying to reduce the csv file records by matching specific strings. I want to write the rows of the matching one to a new csv file.

Here is an example dataset:

[image: dataset screenshot]

What I am trying to do is search by going through all of the rows for specific matching keywords (e.g. only write the rows containing WARRANT ARREST as can be seen on the image) to a new csv file.

Here is my code for so far:

```
import csv
with open('test.csv', 'a') as myfile:
        with open('train3.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
            spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
            for r in spamreader:
                for field in row:
                    if field == "OTHER OFFENSES":
                        myfile.write(r)
```

`test.csv` is empty and `train3` contains all the records.

Comment: Take a look to https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html

Comment: You can often learn a lot about what's going on by simply adding some `else` statements. For instance, after `if field == "OTHER OFFENSES":`, you could write `else: print(field)` or `else: print(r)`. It might become obvious why your comparison fails once you see the actual data. E.g. there might be a newline character after each row that's messing up the comparison (that was the cause of the problem the last time someone asked about this and I answered). Instead of `if field == "OTHER OFFENSES"`, you could try `if "OTHER OFFENSES" in field:`

Comment: In your dataset example, there isn't a single field that equals `"OTHER OFFENSES"`. So you would expect the output file to be empty.

Comment: What specifically is your question?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following approach, it is a bit difficult to test as your data cannot be copy/pasted:

```
import csv

with open('test.csv', 'a', newline='') as f_outputcsv, open('train3.csv', 'r') as f_inputcsv:
    csv_spamreader = csv.reader(f_inputcsv)
    csv_writer = csv.writer(f_outputcsv)

    for row in csv_spamreader:
        for field in row:
            if field == "WARRANT ARREST":
                csv_writer.writerow(row)
                break
```

This uses a `csv.writer` instance to write whole rows back to your output file.

Comment: Thanks Martin, that worked fine! I just had to change the argument ab to a and rb to r!

Comment: Great, are you using Python 3? If so, it would be better as `'a', newline=''`

Comment: yes I am working with Anaconda - python 3.5. Thanks again!

Comment: Glad to help, don't forget to click the grey tick next to the answer to accept the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can often learn a lot about what's going on by simply adding some `else` statements. For instance, after `if field == "OTHER OFFENSES":`, you could write `else: print(field)` or `else: print(r)`. It might become obvious why your comparison fails once you see the actual data.

There might also be a newline character after each row that's messing up the comparison (that was the cause of the problem the last time someone asked about this and I answered). Perhaps python sees `OTHER OFFENSES\n` which does not equal `OTHER OFFENCES`. To match these, use a less strict comparison or `strip()` the field.

Try replacing `if field == "OTHER OFFENSES"` with `if "OTHER OFFENSES" in field:`. When you do `==` you're asking for an exact match whereas `something in something_else` will search the whole line of text for `something`.